# gradle project dependency in multi project setup to include jar alone

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

In my gradle build script, I have multiple projects. Few of them have dependency on the nested projects.

```
rootProject
  proj-1
  proj-2
  proj-3
```

In build script

```
project('proj-2) {
    dependencies { 
      compile (
         project(':proj-1'),
         //few other dependencies
       )
   } 
}
```

proj-1 has sources, tests and main jar artifacts. 
proj-2 is a webapp. While building war file, war included tests and sources jar of proj-1.

How do I exclude tests and sources of proj-1 and just include the actual jar?
For group:mod:artifact:version compile dependencies we specify @jar classifier. Is there something similar for project(':proj-1') dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Your notation is a little weird... try just this

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':proj-1')
}
```

It should not pull in the tests.